# Issue with simple quote in bat file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I am trying to execute bat file containing a loop.
When executing a loop, the file execution is aborted.

I modified a little the command to understand what is the error and it seems I cannot put simple quote into the loop.

```
/f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i IN ("version=X.Z.W") do set VERSION=%%j    -> success
/f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i IN ('version=X.Z.W') do set VERSION=%%j    -> failure
```

It is annoying as `version=X.Z.W` should be returned by `findstr /B /c:"%var%=" ..\..\file.properties`

I tested on different desk, and this issue occurs only on my computer.
Do you know if there is any settings to modify?

I have the issue when typing the command directly into a command prompt.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm gonna have to ask for specifics: 1. What OS is each computer running (including service pack), 2. what file are you trying to perform a `FINDSTR` on? Is it a system file/log, personal file, etc (please include file extension).

Answer (score 0):

If you are typing the above directly into a command prompt, it will fail because you have used `%%` instead of `%`. Windows CMD doesn't read `%%` as it does processing a batch file.

And the `'` as opposed to `"` are read differently by CMD. `'` is read as a command where `"` is read as a literal string.

Comment: Hello,
Indeed, %% has to be used in batch file.

the command line:
 /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %i IN ('findstr /B /c:"%var%=" ....\file.properties') do set VERSION=%j

does not work on my command line, but it does on another computer. Variable var was already set to "version"

Comment: so the command that is failing is `FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %i IN ('findstr /B /c:"%var%=" ....\file.properties') DO set VERSION=%J` ?